# When would fruit trees start bearing fruits if they're propagated with the layering method?

Tags: fruit-trees, propagation, air-layer

Many fruit trees take years to bear fruits. For example, apple trees can take two to seven years depending on their rootstock, and up to around 10 years if seed grown. Another interesting example is Monkey puzzle trees as they take between 30 and 40 years to start producing!

One advantage of the air layering propagation method is that you can root branches old enough to have fruit spurs. In this video, they successfully rooted a 3" thick maple tree branch!
https://youtu.be/p1z7O4JQOIA?t=45

Let's say I air layer a tree with the right ages of fruit bearing branches, would it be able to bear fruit immediately?

Comment: The branch _is_ still mature, it doesn't recognize it _is_.

Comment: When you say it doesn't recognize that it's mature, do you mean that it you'll have to wait two to seven more years before fruit bearing?

Comment: I said recognize because you used that word before the edit. What I mean is that a tree or branch can't recognize or think. It is what it is, so if the branch was already bearing fruit it still will.